# Batch Renaming Files - 27 out of 303 files not processed due to "could not find part of path"

Tags: c#

I am doing a simple operation of renaming files in a folder. Out of the 303 files, 28 are not being renamed due to the "could not find part of path error".

This is confusing b/c all of the original files are of the same sequential nomenclature and I have checked that the paths 'do' exist. I had thought this was a network error since I am writing to a network folder; however, it also occured when I attempted to write to a local folder.

Also, I have tried combining the newPaths with Path.Combine as well as regular concatenation... same result both times.

Thank you for the help.

Here is my code:

```
// lists
    var newFileNames = new List<string>();
    var prevPaths = new List<string>();

    // directory info operations
    var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    int fileCount = Directory.GetFiles(path).Length;

    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

    // sort directory by creation time
    var sortedFiles = dirInfo.GetFiles()
      .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
      .ToList();

    if (toggle)
    {
      int count = 0;

      foreach (var file in sortedFiles)
      {
        // add strings to fileNames
        string newFileName = count.ToString("D3") + " - " + newNames[count] + ".pdf";
        newFileNames.Add(newFileName);

        // CREATE FILE paths
        string oldPaths = path + sortedFiles[count];
        string newPaths = path + newFileName;

        try
        {
          File.Move(oldPaths, newPaths);
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
          Print(ex.Message);

          if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(oldPaths)))
            Print("filePath does not exists: " + oldPaths);
          if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(newPaths)))
            Print("newfilePath does not exist: " + newPaths);
        }

        count++;
      }
    }

    A = newFileNames;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqSwg.jpg)

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6BzA.jpg)

[image]

Comment: You are only getting the base name without path.  If you want path use FullName property.

Comment: ahh I missed that... thanks for the list. I need to filter out those characters. I had thought it was an issue with the file path.

Answer (score 1):

`/` is an invalid character in filename, it will be treated as a path seperator. You may replace it with a hyphen. You can get a list of invalid path and filename characters with the methods: [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-6.0) and [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?view=net-6.0)

Comment: The files already exist. If the forward slash was invalid than the file would not exist.  I suspect the files came from a Linux system.

Comment: The path in the pink image is the destination.

Comment: Where is the forward slash coming from?  It is not in the code.  The OP must be get the forward slash from a Linux machine.  We need to know if the destination folder is on Window or Linux.  If linux than all the slashes should be forward, and if on windows than backwards.

Comment: Eh.. one thing I need clear up first, could you see the 2 screenshots in the question? Because it's obviously: these files are on Windows, probably download from OneDrive, and probably the forward slash is coming from the chapter title of each file.

Comment: But what system is the destination?

Comment: Still Windows, the destination path is start with "C:\"